# Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\Apteka.exe' while publishing by Click Once

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have this error Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\Apteka.exe' while publishing my project through Click Once. When I rebuild it, it works fine. I am getting this error only while publishing from Click Once. I am using Windows Vista and Visual Studio Professional 2010.

Comment: Are you using VS 2010 or VS 2012?  Your tag is 2010 but you say 2012 in the text?  Pretty sure you can't install 2012 on Vista.

Comment: @ScottWylie Yes you are right, I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I did mistake and edited my question. Do you know why it occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try publishing using the Publish option on the Build menu instead of the Build button on the Publish page. This uses a different path to doing the build. Sometimes when using the button in the publish page, a race condition occurs which ends up with it trying to build the deployment package before the build is completed.